# Unable to update hook after image is uploaded to firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

First of all, thanks for the help...I'm quite new to React and I have NO IDEA why won't my hook update.

So I want to upload an image to firebase, grab the url from firebase, update it with the hook and send it to my db.

```
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [imageURL, setImageURL] = useState({ preview: null, data: null });

  // show preview every time the input changes
  useEffect(() => {
    // ensure image is present on the page and NOT null
    if (image) setImageURL({ preview: URL.createObjectURL(image), data: null });
  }, [image]);

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      if (image) {
        // create reference point to where the image is uploaded to
        const imageRef = ref(storage, `${Date.now()} -- ${image.name}`);

        // upload image & retrieve public url to save in db
        await uploadBytes(imageRef, image);
        const imageUrl = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);

        setImageURL(prev => ({ ...prev, data: imageUrl })); <-- can't update hook
      }

      ...other code

    } catch (err) {
     ... handle error
    }

    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> 
        <label>
          <span>Upload an image</span>
          <input
            type='file'
            accept='image/*'
            onChange={e => setImage(e.target.files[0])}
          />
        </label>
    </form>
```

I am using React 18 and Firebase 9.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...so any help is greatly appreciated!

I have tried using async/await and then/catch, but both no luck

Comment: I think I know what the problem is....

When I clicked submit, my state did update, but just not reflected on the submit function. In another word, my submission is still the old state with imageURL.data = null

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm doing the right thing, but instead of updating the state, I simply post the returned URL from firebase to the db

Updated code:

```
  const [image, setImage] = useState({ file: null, previewUrl: null });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (image.file)
      setImage(prev => ({
        ...prev,
        previewUrl: URL.createObjectURL(image.file),
      }));
  }, [image.file]);

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let uploadedImage = null;

    try {
      if (image.file) {
        uploadedImage = await uploadImage(image.file);
      }

      const res = await axios.post('/api/drinks', {
        image: uploadedImage,
      });

      console.log(res);
    } catch (err) {
        ...handle error
    }
  }
```

Everything works fine now, but again, I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it, so any feedbacks/comments are appreciated!